# What type of syntax is "%u00AB"?

Tags: html, security, unicode, syntax, xss

In [this](http://www.barracudalabs.com/wordpress/index.php/2009/06/05/unicode-encoding-for-bypassing-xss-filters/) article, I'm warned of an XSS attack vector `"%u00ABscript%u00BB"`.  I'm wondering what type of syntax `"%u00AB"` is.  In my brief tests on Chromium, it doesn't actually get rendered into a tag, leading me to believe that the syntax is used by either an SQL engine, or a server side programming language.  I'm not concerned with stored/reflected XSS, only DOM-based ones.  I don't recognize it though, so maybe its like ruby or python or something?

Also, does anyone know if its an issue in other browsers? I only tested Chromium, but perhaps other versions and browsers behave differently and are therefore vulnerable.

Comment: @BoltClock It says they "**sometimes** get translated into ‘<’ and ‘>’, respectively."

Comment: @Martin Smith: That's even more bizarre...

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, that could suggest that either certain quirky rendering engines resolve the syntax while others (like the tested chromium don't), or certain quirky serverside platforms do it, while others doin't.

Comment: @BoltClock - In SQL Server `varchar` columns characters that are not exactly represented in the code page of the column collation can get silently converted to near homoglyphs. Maybe they are talking about content changed in such a way when round tripped to the DB (e.g. entered through a comments section on a form)

Comment: The blog post makes mention of a mailing list posting, so perhaps it would be useful to track that down.  The date of the blog posting could narrow things down a good bit.

Comment: Though there are no collations that I can find in SQL Server where it makes that specific conversion from `«` to `<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a kind of Percent-encoding mechanism know as [non-standard unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations), or `%u encoding`, was  rejected in 2004.

In short, you should by aware of `all the possible combinations of the character "<"`. The best start point is [OWASP XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Character_Encoding).

Answer (score 3):

The `%uhhhh` syntax is a non-standard variant of the well-known percent encoding where one can specify a Unicode character directly by its code point instead of by its encoded code point just like some languages support `\uhhhh`. This syntax is supported by JavaScript’s `unescape` function as well as by Microsft’s IIS web server.

But this is probably not the cause as `%u00AB` will get mapped to `«`. The cause of this is rather some sort of transliteration [like *iconv* supplies](http://ideone.com/rpGXC):

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', '«') === '<<'
iconv('UTF-8', 'KOI8-R//TRANSLIT', '«') === '<<'
```

And according to [Jeremiah Grossman’s blog post *Results, Unicode Left/Right Pointing Double Angel Quotation Mark*](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.de/2009/06/results-unicode-leftright-pointing.html) referring to this vulnerability, the number of vulnerable applications sum up:

> Arian promised to get back to 3APA3A after scanning several hundred production websites using [WhiteHat Sentinel](http://www.whitehatsec.com/home/services/services.html). A huge R&D benefit of the platform. Two years later there is data to share. We’ve been busy, but hey, better late the never right? :) As it turned out 3APA3A was correct! Arian discovered a small number of Web applications vulnerable to the encoding technique and they add up if the sample pool is large enough. Samples ranging from 300 to roughly 1000 websites.